# regression with ratio variables

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, least-squares

I plan do run a regression analysis with ratio defined variables such as (FX loans/ total loans, tangible assets/total assets etc.) and I have only 13 annual observations. This regression is needed to be constructed by balance sheet items like this but the sample continuity breaks down, so I have to use ratios..

Here is an example of my regression:

Tangible Assets/Total Assets = FX Loans/ Total Loans + % Change in Real Exchange Rate + GDP growth rate + ..

My first question is that whether it is OK to run a regression with 13 years.

The second one is about the model specification and variable specification.
Is it OK to run basic OLS, or do I have enough space for taking lag varaibles to run with different estimators?

Is it OK to use the ratios without no modification or should I transform them to log variables for OLS?

Comment: Do you have multiple lines per year? If yes, how many?

Comment: You have don't have enough data to do this well. You have 13 data points and 5+ parameters!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the regression with ratios, with some caveats. It seems unlikely in this case that the residuals will be normally distributed. In that case, the OLS estimator would not be the maximum likelihood estimator and the standard error estimates will be unreliable.

A log transformation provides no theoretical advantage in this case. It may however provide practical benefits in terms of model performance. Unfortunately, it does not sound like you have sufficient data to adequately address out of sample prediction errors.

Comment: I agree that a hard situation. maybe a  bootstrap can be helpful in this case.

Comment: Bootstrap can be helpful for predicting parameter standard errors, particularly when the measurement errors or residuals are not well approximated by any of the commonly used density functions. Unfortunately for Atac, with 13 observations and at least 3 parameters, there are not really any methods that are actually good.